# Uso del password_hash en el login

Tags: php, mysql

Hola estoy realizando el tema de seguridad en mi sitio, inicie realizando la enciptacion de la contraseña utilizando password_hash me encipta la contraseña y la guarda en la base de datos, el problema es que no se como darle la condicional en el logueo, es decir que me esta logeando con la contraseña encriptada y no con la que se le asigno

ESTE ES MI CODIGO PHP EN EL REGISTRO

```
<?php

include ("../conexion.php");

//confirmar que todos los datos se envian correcto y no estan vacios
if(isset($_POST ['usuarios']) && !empty($_POST['usuarios']) &&
isset($_POST ['apellidos']) && !empty($_POST['apellidos']) &&
isset($_POST ['nusuario']) && !empty($_POST['nusuario']) &&
isset($_POST ['correo']) && !empty($_POST['correo']) &&
isset($_POST ['contrasenia']) && !empty($_POST['contrasenia']) &&
isset($_POST ['rcontrasenia']) && !empty($_POST['rcontrasenia'])&&

$_POST ['contrasenia'] == $_POST ['rcontrasenia'])

{
  $pass=$_POST['contrasenia'];
  $passHash=password_hash($pass,PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
  if(
  $rol=isset($_POST['rol'])){
  $rol=='1';
  }else{
  $rol=='2';
  }

 $query = "INSERT INTO usuario VALUES(null,'$_POST[usuarios]','$_POST[apellidos]','$_POST[nusuario]','$passHash','$_POST[correo]','$_POST[rol]','$_POST[Estado]')";

$message=$conn->query($query);

  header("Location: ../Registro.php?mensaje=true");
} else {
  header("Location: ../Registro.php?mensaje2=true");
}

?>
```

ESTE ES MI CODIGO PHP EN EL LOGIN 
como puedo implementarle aqui que me tome la contraseña inicial con la que se registro, gracias

```
<?php
 include ("../conexion.php");

    $correo=$_POST['correo'];
    $contrasenia=$_POST['contrasenia'];
 if($operario="SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE usuario='$correo' AND contrasenia='$contrasenia'AND Rol_idRol='1' AND Estado='1'"){
    $result=$conn->query($operario);

 if($result->num_rows>0){  }
    $row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  if($contrasenia==$row['contrasenia']){

        session_id('operario');
        session_start('operario');
        echo"bienvenido" . $_SESSION['operario'];
          //echo "<br><br><a href=../index.php</a>";
        header('Location:http://localhost/php-login/menuO.php');
    exit();
  }else if(
    $administrador="SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE usuario='$correo' AND contrasenia='$contrasenia'AND Rol_idRol='2' AND Estado='1'"){
    $result=$conn->query($administrador);

    if($result->num_rows>0){  }
      $row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if($contrasenia==$row['contrasenia']){



       echo"bienvenido" . $_SESSION['administrador'];
       //echo "<br><br><a href=../index.php</a>";
       header('Location:http://localhost/php-login/menuA.php');
       exit();



}else{
  header("Location: ../index.php?fallo=true");
 mysqli_close($conn);
}

}
}

   ?>
```

Comment: cual es el error que te da?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para comprobar una contraseña generada usando [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php) debes de utilizar la función `password_verify()`  que comprueba que la contraseña coincida con un hash generado.

**Ejemplo:**

```
if (password_verify($contrasenia, $row['contrasenia'])) {
    echo '¡La contraseña es válida!';
} else {
    echo 'La contraseña no es válida.';
}
```

[Documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php)

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que tienes que hacer es comparar en la consulta con el password encriptado, para eso se usa la función password_verify:

```
    <?php
 include ("../conexion.php");

    $correo=$_POST['correo'];
    $contrasenia=$_POST['contrasenia'];
 if($operario="SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE usuario='$correo' AND Rol_idRol='1' AND Estado='1'"){
    $result=$conn->query($operario);

 if($result->num_rows>0){  }
    $row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  if(password_verify($contrasenia,$row['contrasenia'])){

        session_id('operario');
        session_start('operario');
        echo"bienvenido" . $_SESSION['operario'];
          //echo "<br><br><a href=../index.php</a>";
        header('Location:http://localhost/php-login/menuO.php');
    exit();
  }else if(
    $administrador="SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE usuario='$correo' AND Rol_idRol='2' AND Estado='1'"){
    $result=$conn->query($administrador);

    if($result->num_rows>0){  }
      $row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if(password_verify($contrasenia,$row['contrasenia'])){



       echo"bienvenido" . $_SESSION['administrador'];
       //echo "<br><br><a href=../index.php</a>";
       header('Location:http://localhost/php-login/menuA.php');
       exit();



}else{
  header("Location: ../index.php?fallo=true");
 mysqli_close($conn);
}

}
}

   ?>
```

Comment: intente poniendolo como un where en la consulta y no da, da error a todos

 WHERE usuario='$correo' AND contrasenia='$passHash'AND Rol_idRol='2' AND Estado='2'"){

Comment: Es cierto, edito mi respuesta, lo que tienes que usar es password_verify